# How to create an unmapped field thlt contains the ids of all entities from a OneToMany mapping

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I'm working inside a spring framework, using the spring-data library built on top of the spring hibernate/persistence layer. I have two entities:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table("parent")
public class Parent {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.All)
  public Set<Child> children;
}

@Entity
@Table("child")
public class Child {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Parent parent;

  @Column(name = "parent_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private String parentId
}
```

I created the parentId field so that I could access the parentId easily without the loading the parent, but had access to lazily load the parent if needed.

I was wondering if there was a way to do something similar in the Parent class, where a field,

```
Set<String> childIds
```

contain the full list of child ids associated with the parent?

I know how to create queries in the repositories to get a list of children (or even populate the entire entity include childIds). However, I was hoping tehre was a way just using the javax persistence annotations approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an ElementCollection. It can be used for basic type collection mapping. Like in your case the children String ids. Out of my head something like:

```
 @ElementCollection
 @CollectionTable(name="child", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
 @Column(name=<Column>)

 public Set<String> childIds ;
```

Please also take a look at [ElementCollection](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Example_of_an_ElementCollection_relationship_to_a_basic_value_database)